# Dynamically set margin in Angular 2 resets after clicking away

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have built a SPA with a couple of pages and a fixed top navbar. I'd like to set a dynamic margin top for the content below the header in every page, which automatically set when the particular page is loaded or resized.

Since the components are siblings, I have set up a shared service to communicate between them.

```
//shared.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  marginTop = new Subject<number>();
  marginTop$ = this.marginTop.asObservable();
  setMarginTop(data: number) {
    this.marginTop.next(data);
  }
}
```

It gets the height of the navbar:

```
//header.component.ts

export class HeaderComponent {
  @HostListener('window: load') calcNavbarHeightOnLoad() {
    this.getNavbarHeight();
  }
  @HostListener('window: resize') calcNavbarHeightOnResize() {
    this.getNavbarHeight();
  }

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {

  }

  getNavbarHeight() {
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.navContainer');
    const navbarHeight = navbar.clientHeight;
    console.log(navbarHeight);
    this._sharedService.setMarginTop(navbarHeight);
  }
}
```

and passes the data to Menu1Component:

```
//menu1.component.ts

export class Menu1Component implements AfterViewInit {
  marginTop: number;
  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._sharedService.marginTop$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.marginTop = data;
      });
  }
}
```

It's working well until I click to another page (menu2). When I go back to the landing page (menu1), the margin disappears.

See the demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/djZaAVdZie2s132MHbLh?p=preview

I also tried lifecycle hooks on the HeaderComponent with no success.

How can I set the margin so that the landing page (menu1) component "remembers" the settings? (Note: the margin is not calculated here for some reason upon loading - anyway, it is calculated on localhost - so pls resize the window to get the margin calculated. Sorry about that. The margin is only set in menu1 for demo purposes but will be set for every page if/when I have the solution.)

Comment: you have messed the code! why subjects are used?

Comment: your problem is edited and solved https://plnkr.co/edit/rSc0Fq3Orpv5xWWNjgzs?p=preview

Comment: @BabarBilal, awesome, it's working like charm! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remember the value use BehaviorSubject. It will always emt the last value till the observable completed.

```
marginTop = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Also don't forget to unsubscribe from your 'this._sharedService.marginTop$.subscribe' subscription in ngOnDestroy method.